# How to remove duplicate characters from a string?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

How do you remove duplicate characters in a string **without converting the string to a list**. I want to delete all duplicate characters in a string (i.e. get the unsorted union of characters). For example string like `"113233454766"` should give me string `"1324576"`. Note order.

I tried this:

```
 StringReplace["113233454766", a___ ~~ x_ ~~ b___ ~~ x_ ~~ c___ :> a ~~ x ~~ b ~~ c]
```

But it won't give me answer. I think I'm not fully understand about pattern.

Comment: Do you need them to be in the same order?

Comment: yes. I need them to be in same order

Comment: Why do you not want to convert the String to a list of characters?  Since it is probably the most natural approach, as your comment implicitly acknowledges, I think you should explain why you find it unacceptable.

Comment: The reason I do not want to convert them to list is memory usage. I have large list of strings. I want to remove duplicates in each string parallely. If I convert all of strings to list before apply DeleteDuplicates prallely, then I need more memory to hold that list. So That's why I thought to keep them as string. May be I am wrong. Mr.Wizard can you shed light on this. My data file for case 10 is 3GB, case 11, 30GB, case 12 300GB. So, I want to build algorithm which use less memory.

Comment: @Vajira What are "case 10", "case 11", etc.?

Comment: @rm -rf In 1995, Dror Bar-Natan compute dimension of vassiliev knot invarients up to 9. http://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/papers/OnVassiliev/ First you build chord diagrams which represent knots. http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/12/13/chord-diagrams/. After that you take out 1T and 4T relations. Dror stop at case 9 because data files really big. In 1997 Jan A. Kneissler computed dimensions upto 12 http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9706022. They compute rational basis. I want to compute different type basis for my research. So case 10,11,12 are stand for chord diagram of order 10,11,12.

Comment: @Vajira Can you avoid converting all strings to lists, but just convert each string when it is processed in its sub-kernel?

Comment: @Michael E2 Yes I can do that. But suppose we have one string. Which one is fast?Split to character->delete duplicate or delete duplicate without splitting it to character?? Any idea??

Comment: @Vajira See my answer for timings.  Unless someone finds a fast way of deleting duplicates in a `String`, it looks like splitting to character codes then deleting is faster.

Comment: @Michael E2. I agree. When I tried to delete duplicates without converting them to characters it become very slow.

Comment: @Michael E2. At beginning I thought if I can delete duplicates without converting them to string I may save some memory and make program fast. But it look like my program getting very slow when I do that. So best way I think convert each string to characters when it is processed. May be I should change the question statement

Comment: @Vajira  No, it's a good question, even if now you decide you want to do something else.  You could ask another question, if it's sufficiently different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll add this one:

```
FromCharacterCode @ DeleteDuplicates @ ToCharacterCode @ "113233454766"
```

> "1324576"

---

#### Comparison

First, @belisarius' and @IstvánZachar have the only solutions that do not convert the string to a list. So +1 for that.  But they're somewhat to very slow.  I'll use Beowulf as an example string:

```
text = ExampleData[{"Text", "BeowulfOldEnglish"}];
```

Timings:

István has one that is the same idea as mine, but it uses `Characters` instead of `ToCharacterCode`.  The other one of his I include is the faster of the two that do not convert the string to a list.

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

FromCharacterCode@DeleteDuplicates@ToCharacterCode@text // timeAvg  (* Michael E2)
StringJoin@DeleteDuplicates@Characters@text // timeAvg              (* Istvan's fastest *)
Block[{f}, f[x_] := (f[x] = ""; x);                                 (* Istvan's String *)
  StringReplace[text, x_ :> f@x]] // timeAvg
FixedPoint[                                                         (* belisarius *)
  StringReplace[#, a___ ~~ x_ ~~ b___ ~~ x_ ~~ c___ :> a ~~ x ~~ b ~~ c] &,
  text] // timeAvg
```

> 0.00130796
> 0.0344223
> 0.090330
> 56.499878

Memory:

```
ByteCount@text
ByteCount@ToCharacterCode@text
ByteCount@Characters@text
```

> 124528
> 900312
> 5401088

One can see that `ToCharacterCode` uses roughly eight times the memory.  (It converts the string to packed array.)  `Characters` is very wasteful of memory, using roughly 45 times the amount as `String`.

On the other hand, if I start from a fresh kernel, `MaxMemoryUsed[]` returns about 56MB.  We can compare how much memory is used by evaluating `MaxMemoryUsed[]` after running a method.  For this test, I joined 100 copies of Beowulf.   Mine used 241MB and for István's used 629MB.  For @belisarius' it was about 113MB when I aborted it as it would take too long to run to completion.

Test code (substitute a desired method for the third line):

```
text2 = StringJoin[Table[#, {i, 100}] &@ ExampleData[{"Text", "BeowulfOldEnglish"}]];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
FromCharacterCode@DeleteDuplicates@ToCharacterCode@text2;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

<strike>If eight times greater is too much, you might consider splitting the string, deleting duplicates in each pieces, combining the results, and deleting again.</strike>

From a comment by the OP, it seems there are lots of strings, and perhaps the longest string may not be overly large.  If so, then the strings may be processed separately (and in parallel, as desired).

Answer (score 12):

Some other methods, without using the string patternmatcher (i.e. converting string to list):

```
s = Characters@"113233454766";
StringJoin @@ (First /@ Tally@s)
StringJoin@DeleteDuplicates@s
StringJoin@Block[{f}, f[y_] := (f[y] = Sequence[]; y); f /@ s]
```

Similar as the last one with the string patternmatcher (without converting to list):

```
Block[{f}, StringReplace[s, {x_ :> If[TrueQ@f@x, "", f@x = True; x]}]]
Block[{f}, f[x_] := (f[x] = ""; x); StringReplace[s, x_ :> f@x]]
```

They all return:

> ```
> 1324576
> ```

Answer (score 11):

```
FixedPoint[
      StringReplace[#, a___ ~~ x_ ~~ b___ ~~ x_ ~~ c___ :> a ~~ x ~~ b ~~ c] &, "13233454766"]
```

> 1324576

Comment: Regex version: `FixedPoint[StringReplace[#, RegularExpression["(\\d)(.*)(\\1)"] -> "$1$2"] &, str]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
"" <> (Characters@ "113233454766" //. {a___, x_, b___, x_, c___} :> {a, x, b, c})

(* "1324576" *)
```

Comment: The OP wrote **"without converting the string to a list"** and `Characters`does exactly that :)

Comment: @belisarius I didn't notice that before :)

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do it without converting the string to a list. You have to define the character range.

```
rest[x_ /; x == {}] := {}
rest[x_] := Rest[x]

str = "113233454766";
(str = StringReplacePart[str, "", rest@StringPosition[str, #]]) & /@ CharacterRange["1", "9"];
str
```

> "1324576"

When I tried this with Michael E2's test, not being able to find the full character range though, it came in at 72 seconds. Had I found the full character range it would have been slower, but then again the full character range of a typical text is not the same as old English.